# How to get the recent values of grouped result?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is the document which has an array name datum and I want to filter the records based on StatusCode, group by Year and sum the amount value from the recent record of distinct Types.

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fce46ca6ac9808276dfeb8c"),
    "year" : 2018,
    "datum" : [ 
        {
            "StatusCode" : "A",
            "Type" : "1",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("100"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }, 
        {
            "StatusCode" : "A",
            "Type" : "1",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("300"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2023-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }, 
        {
            "StatusCode" : "A",
            "Type" : "2",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("420"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2032-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        },
        
        {
            "StatusCode" : "B",
            "Type" : "2",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("420"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2032-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

In my case following is the expected result :

```
{
  Total : 720
}
```

I want to achieve the result in the following aggregate Query pattern

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $addFields: {
          datum: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$datum",
              initialValue: {},
              "in": {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      { $in: ["$$this.StatusCode", ["A"]] }                     
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$this",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$year",
          RecentValue: { $sum: "$datum.Amount" }
        }
      }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first $unwind the `datum` array. Do the filtering and sort by the date. Then get the record with latest datum by a $group. Finally do another $group to calculate the sum.

Here is a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/we-yO-nNGLh) for your reference.

Comment: how to achieve the result without unwind  and can not we do in reduce function ?

Comment: Is there any special reason that $reduce is preferred..?

Comment: yes like to avoid unwind and it should be more than 1 million records to process.